# Is there any way to let apple know shellshock patch download is broken?

Tags: macos, security, bash

I am trying to patch Lion (10.7.5).
According to shellshocker.net, I am vulnerable to 6 out of 7 possible exploits.
The download link for Lion is broken:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1767?locale=en_US
leads me to the following empty file:
https://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1767/en_US/BashUpdateLion.dmg

Is there anyway to report this without paying 30 for tech support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That DL article works for me on 10.10 - Do you have another browser or computer to do the download? If not, you might have to go to a friend's or Apple Store and get help directly from the genius bar.

There is no charge for in-store help and you probably can resolve this with a USB stick and a different browser/OS combination.

Also, I've put a [link to the dmg on dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70165730/BashUpdateLion.dmg), but you really, really shouldn't trust internet downloads unless [you can checksum the file](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202369) and are confident it's as safe as what you'd get from Apple directly.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried another comp, but same result on osx 10.8.5. Just a dead link. I will try another network when I get into office. Then another OS.  I didn't use the file you provided because the SHA1 fingerprint didn't match the support article linked to. I'll post update when I can try again.

Comment: @dval Both links you posted still work for me on Mac and iOS devices. Sorry the Dropbox didn't work. I'll take that down. Something might be up with your network or DNS - hard to tell.

Comment: Well, I didn't have any issues from a Comcast business connection. Still can't download over Fios. Thanks for your help.